# Profile check and number

Tags: support

There is a question I have regarding profile views as shown on my homepage. If a person views a profile twice then will the homepage mentioned it as two profile views or one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with most queries about the StackExchange engine, [you go to Mother Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132688/how-are-profile-views-counted),

> it is always caching.

If the person views it *after* the cache has been cleared ([say 15-20 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869800/how-long-are-files-usually-kept-in-a-browsers-cache), depending on your usage), then it seems to count as a second view.